# Scale the filter output

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, signal-processing

I have a subfunction which uses a Sobel operator. In this problem, I have to scale the filter output to the interval `[0,1]` for comparison with a threshold value which is also in the range `[0,1]`. How should I improve this function?

```
function [ image_out ] = Sobel(image, threshold)
image=imread(image);
image_out=edge(image,'sobel');

maskx=[-1 0 1; -2 0 2;-1 0 1];
masky=[1 2 1; 0 0 0 ;-1 -2 -1];

resx=conv2(Image, maskx);
resy=conv2(Image, masky);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with your code.  Your first two lines of code:

```
image=imread(image);
image_out=edge(image,'sobel'); %// typo - should have been image, not Image - I fixed this.
```

already finds the edges with the Sobel operator.  I'm also confused with your first line.  Is `image` a string that is the filename of your image?  You haven't made that clear.... so I'll assume it is.  In any case, you can additionally specify a third argument which is between `[0-1]` that specifies what threshold you would like the edges to be found at.  However, my guess is that you don't want to do this and you would like to perform the filtering operation yourself.  Once you convolve with your image with the horizontal and vertical gradients, then find the **magnitude** with these components, scale this output to `[0-1]`, then apply your threshold.  I would convert your image to double using [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) to allow for floating point precision... especially if we are going to calculate the magnitude.

Therefore, your function would actually be:

```
function [ image_out ] = Sobel(image, threshold)
image = imread(image);
image = im2double(image); %// Change to double
maskx = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2;-1 0 1]; 
masky = [1 2 1; 0 0 0 ;-1 -2 -1];

resx = conv2(image, maskx, 'same'); %// Filter the image - Make sure you use the 'same' flag
resy = conv2(image, masky, 'same');

mag = sqrt(resx.^2 + resy.^2); %// Compute magnitude
mag = (mag - min(mag(:))) / (max(mag(:)) - min(mag(:))); %// Scale to [0-1]
image_out = mag >= thresh; %// Now apply threshold
```

I've made a few changes to your code.  Specifically, when using `conv2`, you need to make sure that you use the `'same'` flag so that the output is the same size as the input image.  We compute the horizontal and vertical gradients, then compute the magnitude.  We rescale the magnitude so that it lies between `[0,1]`, then threshold the image with `thresh` which is also in the range of `[0,1]`.  Any locations that have intensities greater than or equal to this value gets set to logical `true` while all other values get set to logical `false`.

---

If I can suggest something, I would use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) instead to filter your images instead of `conv2`.  `conv2` is for general 2D signals while `imfilter` is specifically designed to filter images.  As such, perhaps replace your `conv2` calls with this:

```
resx = imfilter(image, maskx, 'replicate', 'conv');
resy = imfilter(image, masky, 'replicate', 'conv');
```

---

Good luck!